# I have built a site using codeigniter the site is working fine in the Live server But Not working in localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Facing problems in completing the forms in the localhost

1. After registration, the same page is refreshed
2. After login blank page is displayed

   Can anyone help me in setting this up

   thank You in advance

I have changed in index.php from production to development But not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please also share the code and your attempts to resolve the problem. Does the server's error log contain any information?

Comment: Also, are you sure this problem is related to phpMyAdmin? That is a pure web frontend for MySQL, and it should not influence how your application is working

Comment: the website is working but operations which contain the form are not working like register,login and forgot password

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it